# flip book created by createjs and preload js and it's take 15 min. to load the page

Tags: javascript, canvas, createjs, page-load-time, preloadjs

flipbook created by createjs and preload js and it takes 15 min. to load the page.
it contains more than 300 images.
http://www.mentalimage.com.au/perkins/05/index.html
How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a little bit of filesize back by optimizing your pngs using something like [ImageOptim](https://imageoptim.com/).

There are also a bunch of duplicate frames. For example, the same open animation plays again when closing, so frames 30 & 70 are identical. You could reuse different frames to reduce this

However, the approach you have taken for your assets is not optimal. Building this as a full frame-by-frame image sequence is not ideal.

- Consider animating separate pieces, so things like the people frames can only be exported once, and the page flip is a separate PNG sequence. Tools like Adobe Animate can help with this, and also export your content directly to an EaselJS library
- You might want to use a video instead. A frame-by-frame animation is going to be VERY heavy, especially at the dimensions you are using.

Overall, I would recommend a different approach to your animation. If you don't want to rebuild it to be more dynamic, then video would be a better approach.